# Unable to connect to mysql after automating mysql-server installation in bash script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, unix

Generates a random string:

`passdb="$(< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c${1:-2};)"`

Feeds **passdb** to debconf i.e to set random passwords for mysql users:

`debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password $passdb'
debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password $passdb'
apt-get -y install mysql-server`

It get's installed successfully but I'm getting an error after firing this query from my bash script: :

Query:

```
mysql --user=root --password=$passdb --execute="CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`$DOMAIN_NM$CONCAT\`; grant all on \`$DOMAIN_NM$CONCAT\`.* to 'wordpressuser'@'localhost' identified by '$OUTPUT1'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: If I recall correctly, single quotes do not expand variables in bash. What does it look like when you `echo` it?

Comment: Echo gives me a random string like OG7iPChw

Comment: Out of curiousity... Can you log in using a literal `$passdb` as password? Like `--password=\$passdb`

Comment: And `debconf-get-selections` what displays? (its in the debconf-utils package)

Comment: I just ran it through it doesn't. I'm suspicious if `debconf` takes a variable?

Comment: @PerroVerd : sorry I didn't understand your question?

Comment: With debconf-get-selections you can display the values of the debconf variables. You need to check that the value that you input (in your case passdb) its changed to the proper one after executing your commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Álvaro its right about the quotes, try something like

```
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password $passdb"
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password $passdb"
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with above changes: `Can't open h8: No such file or directory at /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections line 114.`

Comment: I changed the answer to use doble quotes, also your pass generate function is using only 2 characters for pass try to change the -2 to something better like -10